# Parse typescript file to get exported const variables

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, parsing

Is there a way to parse the environment.ts file from a .js file?

```
export const environment = {
    ...,
    production: false,
    ...
};
```

something like

> beforePrepare.js

```
module.exports = function (ctx) {
    let environmet = TOOL.parse(src/environments/environment.ts);
    console.log(environment); --> PRINT {..., production: false, ...}
}
```

Could a regex also do the work?

I need this to implement a [cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/appdev/hooks/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex can be used as a quick-and-dirty solution:

```js
const s = `
// Some comment
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-api-url',
  testUser: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 25
  }
};
export const otherStuff = {
  answer: 42
};
`;

const regex = /export const environment = (\{[^;]*\});/m;
const match = regex.exec(s);
const environment = eval(`(${match[1]})`);
console.log(environment);
```

For more complex cases you need a TypeScript parser.

Comment: Hey kol! Thank you for your time. This works fine, but I also have nested variables like: production: false, experiment: {...} and it does not work for this. Is there a way to export nested objects also? Do you have a ts parser to recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: I modified my answer. My solution assumes there is a semicolon after the closing brace of the `environment` object.

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I should really learn regex :) cheers